# Android Studio Provide a deafult constructor

Tags: java, android, android-bluetooth

I have a problem with my app. It's already running, but now I've added Bluetooth and since then the pages keep crashing.

All 10 classes have the same structure and all 10 have the same error:

> This class should provide a default constructor (a public constructor
> with no arguments)
> (`com.example.feuerwerkzndanlage.empfaenger_1_zuenden`)

Code Activity:

```java
package com.example.feuerwerkzndanlage;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class empfaenger_1_zuenden extends AppCompatActivity{

    private final ConnectedThread mConnectedThread; // bluetooth background worker thread to send and receive data

    public empfaenger_1_zuenden(ConnectedThread mConnectedThread){
        this.mConnectedThread = mConnectedThread;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.empfaenger_1_zuenden);

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence back_txt = "Zurück!";
        CharSequence rot_txt = "Zünden!";
        CharSequence gruen_txt = "Reset!";
        int a = 0;
        AtomicInteger b = new AtomicInteger(0);
        AtomicInteger c = new AtomicInteger(0);
        AtomicInteger d = new AtomicInteger(0);
        AtomicInteger e = new AtomicInteger(0);
        AtomicInteger f = new AtomicInteger(0);
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        ImageView back = findViewById(R.id.back);
        Button zuenden1_1 = findViewById(R.id.btn_zuenden1_1);
        Button zuenden1_2 = findViewById(R.id.btn_zuenden1_2);
        Button zuenden1_3 = findViewById(R.id.btn_zuenden1_3);
        Button zuenden1_4 = findViewById(R.id.btn_zuenden1_4);
        Button zuenden1_5 = findViewById(R.id.btn_zuenden1_5);

        Button ruecksetzen = findViewById(R.id.btn_ruecksetzen);

        ImageView kanal_1_1 = findViewById(R.id.kanal1_1);
        ImageView kanal_1_2 = findViewById(R.id.kanal1_2);
        ImageView kanal_1_3 = findViewById(R.id.kanal1_3);
        ImageView kanal_1_4 = findViewById(R.id.kanal1_4);
        ImageView kanal_1_5 = findViewById(R.id.kanal1_5);

        back.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Toast.makeText(context, back_txt, duration).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(empfaenger_1_zuenden.this, zuenden.class));
        });

        ruecksetzen.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Toast.makeText(context, gruen_txt, duration).show();
            kanal_1_1.setImageResource(R.drawable.kanal_gruen);
            kanal_1_2.setImageResource(R.drawable.kanal_gruen);
            kanal_1_3.setImageResource(R.drawable.kanal_gruen);
            kanal_1_4.setImageResource(R.drawable.kanal_gruen);
            kanal_1_5.setImageResource(R.drawable.kanal_gruen);
            b.set(a + 1);
            c.set(a + 1);
            d.set(a + 1);
            e.set(a + 1);
            f.set(a + 1);
        });

        zuenden1_1.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if (b.get() == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(context, rot_txt, duration).show();
                kanal_1_1.setImageResource(R.drawable.kanal_rot);
                b.set(0);

                if(mConnectedThread != null) //First check to make sure thread created
                    mConnectedThread.write("Kanal_1_1_Z");
            }
        });

        zuenden1_2.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if (c.get() == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(context, rot_txt, duration).show();
                kanal_1_2.setImageResource(R.drawable.kanal_rot);
                c.set(0);

                if(mConnectedThread != null) //First check to make sure thread created
                    mConnectedThread.write("Kanal_1_2_Z");
            }
        });

        zuenden1_3.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if (d.get() == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(context, rot_txt, duration).show();
                kanal_1_3.setImageResource(R.drawable.kanal_rot);
                d.set(0);

                if(mConnectedThread != null) //First check to make sure thread created
                    mConnectedThread.write("Kanal_1_3_Z");
            }
        });

        zuenden1_4.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if (e.get() == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(context, rot_txt, duration).show();
                kanal_1_4.setImageResource(R.drawable.kanal_rot);
                e.set(0);

                if(mConnectedThread != null) //First check to make sure thread created
                    mConnectedThread.write("Kanal_1_4_Z");
            }
        });

        zuenden1_5.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if (f.get() == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(context, rot_txt, duration).show();
                kanal_1_5.setImageResource(R.drawable.kanal_rot);
                f.set(0);

                if(mConnectedThread != null) //First check to make sure thread created
                    mConnectedThread.write("Kanal_1_5_Z");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Code Manifest

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.feuerwerkzndanlage">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />

    <permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:label="BLUETOOTH" />
    <permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/logo"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Feuerwerkzündanlage">
        <activity
            android:name=".Musik_Auswahl"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Main_Bluetooth"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".inArbeit"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".zeit_laden_1"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".zeit_speichern_auswahl"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".zeit_ruecksetzen"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".zeit_speichern_1"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".empfaenger_1"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".empfaenger_2"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".empfaenger_3"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".empfaenger_4"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".empfaenger_5"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".empfaenger_6"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".empfaenger_7"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".empfaenger_8"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".empfaenger_9"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".empfaenger_10"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".empfaenger_1_zuenden"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".empfaenger_2_zuenden"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".empfaenger_3_zuenden"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".empfaenger_4_zuenden"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".empfaenger_5_zuenden"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".empfaenger_6_zuenden"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".empfaenger_7_zuenden"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".empfaenger_8_zuenden"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".empfaenger_9_zuenden"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".empfaenger_10_zuenden"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Achtung_Scharf"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Test"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Biometric_Authentication"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".test_arm"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".vorschlaege"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".gesp_feuerwerke"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Auswahl_Planer"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Planer_1"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Planer_2"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Planer_3"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Planer_4"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Planer_5"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Planer_6"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Planer_7"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Planer_8"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Planer_9"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Planer_10"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".zuenden"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Sidebar"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: can you provide error log? thanks

Comment: What is unclear about the error? Your class has a constructor with an argument (of type `ConnectedThread`), and it shouldn't have one (according to the error).

Comment: Unrelated: follow java naming conventions. Class names go CamelCase. And java supports unicode, so you could call it Empfänger1Zünden ... but then: putting NUMBERS into names like this, that is most often: wrong. You absolutely do NOT want to create multiple things that are NAMED _1, _2, _3 ... to then have the same code repeated, dealing with _1, _2, _3 ...

Comment: Instead, you should be using some form of List data structure for example. So that you have 10, or 20, or 50 entries in that list, and then you have code that ITERATES that list, and does things on the entries. Instead of doing all these things manually in code.

Comment: Meaning: **All 10 classes have the same structure and all 10 have the same error** implies that you really doing the wrong thing. What if you want 20 of those things next week?!

Answer (score 1):

1. Because you use the keywords **final**

> ```
> private final ConnectedThread mConnectedThread; // final keywords in Java is a constant.
> ```

2. It's not recommanded create a constructor for Activity, casuse it no need to instantiated by **new** . to communicate between activitys is by using `startActivity()` or `startActivityForResult()`.

> ```
> Intent it = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
> it.putExtra("data", "Hi is FirstAcitvity"); // if you need pass some data to SecondAcrivity
> startActivity(it);
> ```

3. The bluetooth component you can create something like a `BluetoothManager.java` and extends from `IntentService` which is Thread Safty.

   ```
    public class BluetoothMnager extends IntentService {     
    public static final String RESULT_RECEIVER = "RESULT_RECEIVER";
    public static final int RESPONSE_CODE = 200;

    // do anything you need       

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        // Declare Result Receiver
        ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(RESULT_RECEIVER);
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("response", "data");
        receiver.send(RESPONSE_CODE , b);
    }
   ```

   // The Activity Side

   ```
    public MainActivity extends...{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Button bt = new Button(this);
    bt.setText("send services");
    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent it  = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BluetoothMnager.class);
            it.putExtra(BluetoothMnager.RESULT_RECEIVER, mReceiver);
            startService(it);
        }
    });
   ```

> ```
> @Override
>    protected void onResume(){
>      // Declare a ResultReceiver
>      mReceiver = new ResultReceiver(new Handler()){
>         @Override
>         protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
>             super.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
>             if (resultCode == 200){
>                 String response = resultData.getString("response");
>                 Log.d(TAG, "response: " + response);
>                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response, 
>                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>             }
>         }
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply!

one more question how can i send data via bluetooth?

Receive is so described in the code in 3, right?

Unfortunately I'm the first time to do something with Bluetooth and I don't have a clear picture yet :)